# PostgreSQL - how to use equals for null in routine

Tags: postgresql

I have a routine with 4 parameters passed in. Sometimes the last parameter "membership_type " is null but when I use equals it does not return records with null value, it does work if I use "is null" but looking for advice how to make sure both work in the same routine:

```
create or replace function fitnessone_master.get_location_cancellation_count(club_number double precision, date date, member_profile character varying, membership_type character varying) returns integer
    language plpgsql
as $$
declare
   member_count integer;
begin
   return (select count(distinct a.agreement_number) as member_count
   from fitnessone_master.cancelled_accounts a
   where cancel_date = get_location_cancellation_count.date
     and a.club_number = get_location_cancellation_count.club_number
     and a.member_profile = get_location_cancellation_count.member_profile
    and a.membership_type = get_location_cancellation_count.membership_type); 
end;
$$;
```

Comment: You can add a default to the parameter, ... , membership_type character varying default ''... would this help?

Comment: The records are null in the database so I dont think setting it to empty string would resolve the issue. I think I need some kind of IF / ELSE statement

Comment: I see. How about adding a variable,
 ..declare
   mmtype_normal text;
begin
   mmtype = '';
   if not membership_type is null then mmtype = membership_type;
 ...

Comment: When you enter the world of NULL you enter the world of 3-valued logic instead of the normal 2-valued (binary) logic. With null the result of a comparison can be True, False, or Null. Any comparison with NULL results in NULL. Including Null=Null; the result is NULL. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eed535d2732a2ab666c3b81d78ec887f).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `= x`, which will never match `NULL`, you can use [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM x`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE):

```
create or replace function fitnessone_master.get_location_cancellation_count(club_number double precision, date date, member_profile character varying, membership_type character varying) returns integer
    language plpgsql
as $$
declare
   member_count integer;
begin
   return (select count(distinct a.agreement_number) as member_count
   from fitnessone_master.cancelled_accounts a
   where cancel_date = get_location_cancellation_count.date
     and a.club_number = get_location_cancellation_count.club_number
     and a.member_profile = get_location_cancellation_count.member_profile
     and a.membership_type is not distinct from get_location_cancellation_count.membership_type); 
end;
$$;
```